# erro ao tentar editText.setSelection

Tags: android, buffer

Estou tentando aplicar uma máscara em meu EditText, porém quando eu tento digitar um valor além do que é permitido obtenho o erro:

```
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (17 ... 17) ends beyond length 13
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:934)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:527)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:520)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.widget.SpellChecker$SpellParser.init(SpellChecker.java:308)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.widget.SpellChecker.spellCheck(SpellChecker.java:149)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.widget.TextView.updateSpellCheckSpans(TextView.java:7753)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7620)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:7990)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:881)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:389)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:266)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:443)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:216)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:29)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspaceOrForwardDelete(BaseKeyListener.java:90)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspace(BaseKeyListener.java:45)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.onKeyDown(BaseKeyListener.java:151)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.text.method.QwertyKeyListener.onKeyDown(QwertyKeyListener.java:352)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.text.method.TextKeyListener.onKeyDown(TextKeyListener.java:132)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5386)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5206)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2533)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:5446)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1248)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1248)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1248)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1248)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1859)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1361)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2324)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1806)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3300)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3273)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2436)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05

-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-20 17:17:23.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1399):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Esta é minha classe de máscara:

```
package suporte;

import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;

public abstract class Mask {

    public static String unmask(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("[.]", "").replaceAll("[-]", "")
            .replaceAll("[/]", "").replaceAll("[(]", "")
            .replaceAll("[)]", "");
}

    public static TextWatcher insert(final String mask, final EditText ediTxt, final int length) {
        return new TextWatcher() {
            boolean isUpdating;
            String old = "";

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                String str = Mask.unmask(s.toString());
                String mascara = "";
                if (isUpdating) {
                    old = str;
                    isUpdating = false;
                    return;
                }
                int i = 0;
                for (char m : mask.toCharArray()) {
                    if (m != '#' && str.length() > old.length()) {
                        mascara += m;
                        continue;
                    }
                    try {
                        mascara += str.charAt(i);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                isUpdating = true;
                ediTxt.setText(mascara);
                ediTxt.setSelection(mascara.length());
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        };
    }
```

}

Quando eu digito 11.111.111/1111-11 e em seguinda + 1, dá o erro. A máscara que eu passo é: ##.####.###/####-##

Debugando, eu descobri que o erro ocorre em algum momento que a api do android vai tentar usar o buffer do editText, que não sei porque fica com o tamanho 19 (Que no caso é o tamanho da String inserida no EditText) porém deveria ser 18, pois antes do setSelection eu fiz um novo setText.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o ideal é você usar na verdade uma limitação no próprio campo e resolver esse problema.

Seu campo é específico e tem uma máscara específica, então porque deixar ele aberto para mais caracteres do que ele realmente precisa? :)

Um adendo a esse método de aplicar máscara genérica, que é muito bom, é que há um problema aí que é na hora de apagar a máscara vai embora, ficando bem feio.. em casos de telefone, por ex, se você digitou um número a mais e remove e o número final está correto, vai ficar sem a formatação adequada! 
Resolvi essa questão alterando o código acima para este:

```
int i = 0;
if(  str.length() > old.length()){
    for (char m : mask.toCharArray()) {
        if (m != '#') {
        mascara += m;
            continue;
        }else{
            try {
                mascara += str.charAt(i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}else{
    mascara = s.toString();
}
```

Comment: Mas como fazemos para a questão de apagar o texto inserido. Estou com esse erro também.
Analisei seu código, mas vi que você não usou o setSelector

Comment: O código que postei é apenas a parte que deve ser alterada do código original.

Comment: Sim, mas ao implementa-lo tive o mesmo problema. Quando eu tento apagar da erro. Pois o buffer esta na posição antiga ainda e o novo texto já tem um tamanho menor